# JavaScript - get range of entries Map entries

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Since a [JavaScript Map remembers the original insertion order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) I was wondering if there was a (clean) way to get a range of entries? Specifically, I want to get all entries after a certain entry. I thought I could just use the map or forEach function but you cannot use map with Map's and forEach does not pass the index ([Map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have any option but to loop through the entries, either explicitly or using loops in function calls.

> Specifically, I want to get all entries after a certain entry.

I'm going to assume you mean a certain value (rather than key), but the below is easily adjusted for keys instead.

Unless `theMap` has hundreds of thousands or even millions of entries, you can use fairly concise code by using spread to get an array of the entries, `indexOf` to find the target value, and `slice` to get only the ones after it:

```
const values = [...theMap.values()];
const index = values.indexOf(theDesiredStartingValue);
const valuesAfter = index === -1 ? [] : values.slice(index + 1);
```

If you're concern that that's two-three loops through the data (but again, that's really unlikely to matter), you could use a single loop:

```
const valuesAfter = [];
let seen = false;
for (const value of theMap.values()) {
    if (seen) {
        valuesAfter.push(value);
    } else if (value === theDesiredStartingValue) {
        seen = true;
    }
}
```

If you meant by key, I'm thinking you probably want a `Map` as a result:

```
const entries = [...theMap.entries()];
const index = entries.findIndex(([key]) => key === theDesiredStartingKey);
const entriesAfter = new Map(index === -1 ? [] : entries.slice(index + 1));
```

If you're concern that that's two-three loops through the data (but again, that's really unlikely to matter), you could use a single loop:

```
const entriesAfter = new Map();
let seen = false;
for (const [key, value] of theMap.entries()) {
    if (seen) {
        entriesAfter.set(key, value);
    } else if (key === theDesiredStartingKey) {
        seen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. I should have specified the output I was looking for. I meant a Map that only contained the entries (key-value pair) after the target entry (a sort of filter operation). The output could also be an object with key value pairs because at that point I do not care about order entries were added, just that they exist and I can access them.

Comment: @regexAgainstTheMachine - The last two solutions above will give you a `Map`. :-) They do the check by key, but if you need to do it by value instead, it's a small tweak. (I don't think you've said whether the "entry" you're checking against is a key, a value, or both.)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I will be checking by key :)  The last two examples work for my use case, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to make this some sort of iterator function as below

```js
function* entriesAfter(map, entry) {
  let found = false
  for(let e of map.values()){
     if(found)
       yield e;
     else if(e == entry)
       found = true
  }
}

var input = new Map([['foo', 1], ['bar', 2], ['baz', 3], ['bing', 4]]);
for(let item of entriesAfter(input,2))
    console.log(item)
```

Comment: I like that idea.